# R: Simulate Data from Time Series Model

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data:

```
original_data = 
structure(c(0.0673484946363246, 1.60498577968324, 2.17560720076042, 
-0.462112644881693, -0.362558548017185, -0.409784175912771, -1.50281077462568, 
-1.54679086182844, -2.04126893126762, -2.36405436737461, -2.33502837999048, 
-3.3377260458764, -1.83952590732828, -0.615227608762644, -1.44592425513493, 
-0.0689944068158092, 0.886593545815299, 0.407470333087633, 1.02157926770069, 
1.84913131257147, 2.28231326419358, 2.38666064527124, 2.26137014234037, 
1.51647743624253, 0.579159113774915, -0.1553605982434, -0.940111738271506, 
-1.04986711255071, -1.97848353030653, 0.47570730652729, 2.36096876835677, 
0.776657477132709, -0.38613378230079, -0.859489557123323, 0.0776092426130364, 
0.27518252643052, 0.385080403264335, 0.3038288922078, 0.128008175893883, 
1.42825900663426, 1.17862533192707, 2.13333740932208, 0.33783788313484, 
0.167815357824885, 0.458388958393972, 0.540516641318202, 0.790326095048392, 
0.123727997023686, -0.45989996669893, -1.42779831659421, -2.33590036967494, 
-1.52672807099094, -0.346415607403433, 0.0244387737402146, 0.958132422816068, 
2.99387112646868, 2.12532538407553, -1.23038611161811, -0.656160692764933, 
-0.70060176845645, -1.39204998257418, -0.0848620664347555, 0.0745383009668174, 
-1.28990393449485, -1.08092596584957, -0.714925550049128, -0.478747689105208, 
0.10033746202316, -0.156345394127981, 0.402305299325081, 0.278647237183831, 
0.410775681498495, 1.47601720761472, 1.75952742066238, 0.90385746319972, 
1.56074946215844, 2.38947658063762, 2.37948445027549, 1.88578118907996, 
0.599055331453183, 1.46892321698617, 0.825355322456577, 2.44244235163167, 
3.87300923437082, 2.70114943199609, 0.499988615250684, -0.820981754671603, 
-0.519867969126153, -0.455859176275453, -0.719734856547955, -1.52247652095288, 
-1.33916106428666, -1.60641219795264, -2.94575104314255, -2.81485392080855, 
-0.922006351539467, -0.760952129907766, -0.0787457407629829, 
-1.42194442385694, -1.55588170315437), .Tsp = c(1, 100, 1), class = "ts")
```

**I am trying to fit a time series model to this data, and then simulate 10 RANDOM predictions from the LAST AVAILABLE time point.**

For example:

- make a single prediction based on last available data point
- simulate a single data point from arima model based on this previous prediction
- forecast next point based on this previously simulated point
- feed this simulated point into the model and make next prediction
- etc.

This means that if I repeat this again, the entire simulation/forecasts would be different since they are random.

To do this, I tried the following code:

First, I fit the model:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(original_data)
```

Then, I try to simulate 10 new predictions:

```
future_data <- arima.sim(n=10, model=fit)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in arima.sim(n = 10, model = fit) : 
  'ar' part of model is not stationary
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this problem?**

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:** An alternate way to do this? Is this correct?

```
fit <- auto.arima(original_data)

# extract AR and MA coefficients
ar_coeff <- fit$coef[paste0("ar", seq_len(fit$arma[1]))]
ma_coeff <- fit$coef[paste0("ma", seq_len(fit$arma[2]))]

# define a list
model_list <- list(order = c(length(ar_coeff), 0, length(ma_coeff)), ar = ar_coeff, ma = ma_coeff)

# simulate new data points
future_data <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = model_list)
```

**Edit 2: Repeat Simulations**

```
fit <- auto.arima(original_data)

ar_coeff <- fit$coef[paste0("ar", seq_len(fit$arma[1]))]
ma_coeff <- fit$coef[paste0("ma", seq_len(fit$arma[2]))]

model_list <- list(order = c(length(ar_coeff), 0, length(ma_coeff)), ar = ar_coeff, ma = ma_coeff)


simulated_paths <- matrix(NA, nrow = 100, ncol = 10)

# Repeat 
for(i in 1:100) {
  simulated_paths[i,] <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = model_list)
}

# Plot
matplot(simulated_paths, type = "l", lty = 1, 
        xlab = "Time", ylab = "Simulated Value",
        main = "100 Simulated Paths from ARIMA Model")
```

Comment: Which (Edit1, Edit2) seemed more appropriate your use case? Traveling so can't test, following.

Comment: @ Chris: thank you for your reply! I think Edit 2 ... but I am not sure if these simulations are starting from the last observed time point?

Comment: I want to point out that ARIMA requires the data to meet specific statistical assumptions to be valid.  When you received `part of model is not stationary` it tells you the data failed to meet the assumptions necessary for ARIMA. A lot of the statistical tools in R do the math for you, whether the data meets the assumptions or not. However, the results of that statistical test might be completely invalid---- because it wasn't used correctly.

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications! I am trying to learn how I can sequentially simulate points from an ARIMA model based on the last available point. E.g. i have weather measurements: Jan 2020 5mm rain, Feb 2020 7 mm rain .... Oct 2023 2 mm rain. I want to fit the arima model... and based on Oct 2023,  simulate 1 year worth of data.

Comment: If I do something like rnorm(100,10,10)... I will end up simulating 100 random points independent from one another. Using anima, I am looking for something like : p1 = rnorm(1, 1,1), p2 = rnorm(1, p1,1), p3 = rnorm(1, p2, 1) ... etc

Comment: You can consider using the forecast package's`simulate` function to simulate data from your ARIMA model. This function may provide more reliable results in some cases. `simulate(fit, nsim = 10)`

Comment: @ gd047: thank you so much for your reply! Can this function be used to simulate future data points ... from the last actual observed measurement? If you have time, could you please show me how to use this? Thank you so much!

Comment: When you use the simulate function in the context of a time series model like ARIMA, it typically generates simulated values for future time intervals from the last observed measurement.

Comment: @ gd047: thank you so much for these clarifications! I will start reading more about the details of this function. if you have time, can you please show me how to use it correctly in my context? I am worried I might do something incorrectly.

Comment: I recommend referring to the online manual for the 'forecast' package, You can find the manual here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/toolbox.html

Comment: FYI, depending on patterns in the data ARIMA can be great, however, if there aren't distinct and typically repeating patterns (think cyclical) ARIMA may not be great. While it uses the last observation, what about the observations of the last week or the last year?  Pretty sure the discuss the package `forecastML` in the FPP3 book, as well.